# How to use Ctrl+C to kill all background processes started in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

ArchLinux (Manjaro).

I'm running one bash file. It runs 2 processes (commands), using `&`.
But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the program - one process dies, and the other continues to work.

How do I stop both processes? Or how do I write a new script for killing these two processes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Update: `trap` requires removing `SIG` prefix on condition, although some shells support including it. See comment below.

The ampersand "&" runs a command in the background in a new process. When its parent process (the command that runs the bash script in your case) ends, this background process will reset its parent process to init (process with `PID` 1), but will not die. When you press `ctrl+c`, you are sending an interrupt signal to the foreground process, and it will not affect the background process.

In order to kill the background process, you should use the `kill` command with the `PID` of the most recent background process, which could be obtained by `$!`.

If you want the to use `ctrl+c` to kill both the script and background process, you can do this:

```
trap 'kill $BGPID; exit' INT
sleep 1024 &    # background command
BGPID=$!
sleep 1024      # foreground command of the script
```

`trap` modifies the trap handler of the  `SIGINT` (`trap` requires removing the `SIG` prefix but some shell may support including it) so the script will kills the process with `$BGPID` before it exits.

Comment: Using "trap 'kill $BGPID; exit' SIGINT"
I get a 
"SC2039: In POSIX sh, prefixing signal names with 'SIG' is undefined."
I think you have to write 
trap 'kill $BGPID; exit' INT

Comment: @Hettomei Thanks for the input. I double check the trap man page and find that what you suggested is true: the standard requires the condition (the triggering signal) should not have the SIG prefix, and supporting SIG prefix is an extension. Updated the original answer. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html

Comment: Doesn't work. I enter `sh -c "trap 'kill $BGPID; exit' INT; journalctl -f > /tmp/1.log & BGPID=$!; ping localhost"`, then I ^C it, and it prints `sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or`.

Comment: Although, when I enter `trap 'killall journalctl'` explicitly it works, so the idea is legit.

Answer (score 1):

Programs can ignore `Ctrl+c` signal, as they can ignore SIGTSTP as well

You can try `Ctrl+z` in most shells (not always but most of the time)

There are some signals that can not be ignored by the process: SIGKILL, SIGSTOP. You can send the kill command. To kill your frozen process, you have to find the process ID (PID).
use pgrep or ps and then kill it

```
 % kill -9 PID
```